# How do you check what interger is after a string in a user input python?

Tags: python

I am working on a python economic text based game. the user has their wallet and their bank balance. for the user to deposit money from their wallet to their bank, I want them to type

```
pls dep x
```

x being a integer. In my game loop i put down

```
if 'pls dep ' in type or 'pls deposit ' in type:
    ?
```

In the loop I defined type as

```
type = input('>  ')
```

and the loop checks if the player called any of the commands by doing

```
if type == 'a command':
```

The problem I have is that I don't know how to check the integer put in after

```
pls dep (integer)
```

To write in words I want to make it like

```
if player called the command 'pls dep ', check what the number is after 'pls dep '
and if player has that much amount of money, subtract the x from their wallet and
Add x to their bank balance.
```

wallet is

```
player_money = 0
```

and players bank balance is

```
player_bank_money = 0
```

Could anyone help me on how to code(ify) what I said above?

Comment: Is this for discord bot?

Comment: Split the input into words (`words = text.split()`).  If word[0] is "pls" and word[1] is "dep", then word[2] has your number.

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ no it is not but i did get influenced by the bot dank memer. im trying to code it on visual studio code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use built-in names as variables. `type` is a built-in name.

Using `.split` (what Tim Roberts said in the comments):

```py
command = input('>  ')

if 'pls dep ' in command or 'pls deposit ' in command:
    print(f"You deposited {command.split()[2]}")
```

Using `.strip` (Don't do this, this isn't a very good usage of `strip`):

```py
command = input('>  ')

if 'pls dep ' in command or 'pls deposit ' in command:
    print(f"You deposited {command.strip('pls dep ').strip('pls deposit ')}")
```

Implementing money variables (final code):

```py
player_money = 0
player_bank_money = 0

command = input('>  ')

if 'pls dep ' in command or 'pls deposit ' in command:
    dep_money = int(command.split()[2])
    player_money -= dep_money
    player_bank_money += dep_money
    print(f"You have ${player_money} in your wallet. You have ${player_bank_money} is your bank.")
```

Also, if you don't want the command to be case sensitive, use: `command.lower()` before the if conditions.

Comment: You can also add command.lower() so that the code can recognise the command and it will not be case sensitive

Comment: This is not a very appropriate use of `strip`. The explicit argument is used as a collection of characters rather than a string.